# how to add hyphen in dynamic sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-queries

I have a table with columns A,B,C,D (type of varchar).

From a stored procedure i am fetching data from the same table.I am created a dynamic sql query inside the stored procedure for fetching data from the table.

what i want is that,

> need to combine column B and C together with a symbol(hyphen or colon) and display it as a single section.

```
DECLARE @sSQL nvarchar(100);
DECLARE @symbol nvarchar(100);
SET @symbol='-'
SELECT @sSQL = N'SELECT [A], ([B], '+@symbol+', [C]) as Status FROM Table';
EXEC sp_executesql @sSQL
```

above query is not working for me.I need following query as a dynamic query.

```
SELECT A,B+'-'+C as Status FROM Table
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need commas there. Here is the correct syntax:

```
SELECT @sSQL = N'SELECT [A], ([B] + '''+@symbol+''' + [C]) as Status FROM Table';
```

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ':'.   it is not working

Comment: SET @symbol=':' i used this

Comment: Check the answer again